# Informatica issue - transformation

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I want to know how to get latest updated record via Informatica. Suppose I have 10 records in a temporary table. 3 records for Account1, 3 for Account2 and 4 records for Account3. Now out of these 3 accounts, I need fetch only those records which has maximum date value (Latest date) and insert in another temporary table. So which transformations I could use to get this or informatica logic I should use? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the Date column comes from input with unique date , based on that use the aggregator transformation and take the maximum date.
2. If no date column is present, please assign system timestamp but cannot take maximum date from this. You have to go for some other logic like rowid and rownum features.

Comment: Yes AruM, date colunm is coming from input with unique value. So I am doing this by taking a Sorter and Aggregator. With Sorter, I am sorting data with Account and Date fields. It's output I am taking into Aggregator in which I am groub by it on Account field and using Max function of data field. I hope my approach is correct. However I am realy very thankfull for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If the source is DB, we can do it in SQ itself - write a temp table by grouping by the pk field, and select this pk field and max(date). then join this output with the original source based on pk and date. 
for eg:

```
select * from src_table
join ( select pk,max(date) as maxdate from src_table ) aggr_table
on src_table.pk=aggr_table.pk
and src_table.date=aggr_table.maxdate
```

same can be implemented inside informatica using an aggregator and joiner. but since the aggregator source is sq and again it's output is joining with sq, one sorter will be required in between the aggregator and joiner.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregator transformation. You can use sorter transformation first with sorting based on account and date asc.After that you can aggregator transformation (grouping based on account). You dont need to add any condition or grouping function, as aggregator will give last records of every group.